# How can i show this kind of output in dart console, using dart programming language

Tags: dart

Is there anyone who can help me?

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Look at the `padLeft` and `padRight` methods on `String`: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.1/dart-core/String/padLeft.html https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.1/dart-core/String/padRight.html

Comment: I'm trying to  implement  this kind of python code in convert to dart                                   =================python code==============n = 1000
while n > 0:
 for i in range(5):
  print(n, end='\t')
  n = n - 1
 print('')   =====================================================      void main() {
  var n = 1000;

  while (n > 0) {
    if (n % 5 == 0) {
      print('\n');
    } else {
      print('$n   \t');
    }
    n--;
  }
}

Comment: @RashidulIslam What we are just asking for is you show us your own attempt to solve the problem in Dart. We can then guide you to how to make it better.

Comment: Your main problem seems to be that Dart's `print` statement adds a newline. Try importing `dart:io` and use `stdout.write` instead of `print`. Other than that, your code needs a little tweaking, but is otherwise on track.